# IE11 custom toolbar buttons - scripting

Tags: button, scripting, internet-explorer-11, toolbar

This is about IE11, which I know has been deprecated.  But I'm on Win7 and it's still a tool I use.

Here's the issue:

- I have a task that's boring and can be automated on certain external web pages.
- I have created a button within the IE11 Toolbar using the approach described on [this page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa753588(v=vs.85).aspx).  Unfortunately, that page doesn't provide any guidance about what language or file extension should be used for the actual script.
- The button does in fact appear in the toolbar and it finds the file to be executed, and the IE 11 console says that it has "navigated there" when I push the button.  But the script does not actually execute.
- I have tried the file extensions and languages for .bat, .vbs, .js, .wsf, and .htm...just trying to put up a "hello world" message...and nothing works from the browser button even though the scripts execute properly from the command line or URL.
- I have relaxed IE 11's security settings so that it shouldn't be blocking anything. The only IE console messages are informational codes HTML1300 and DOM7011

So...what scripting language/file format will actually work in this use case???

Answer (score 0):

Well, after only a few hours I figured out the only thing that seems to work: the "script" has to be an HTML file and the only language you can use is Javascript. No, you can't execute a .js file from the button...it has to be .htm...